# Patchform autocomplete material in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-material2

I have this example [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-jd4bxn?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts)

I tried to display Florida in City, but for me doesn't work, I can display only 3, city_id.  For this I used this code:

I have 2 Class, Client and City

```
  city: City[] = [
    {
      name: 'Arkansas',
      city_id: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'California',
      city_id: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Florida',
      city_id: '3'
    },
    {
      name: 'Texas',
      city_id: '4'
    }
  ];
  client: Client[] = [
    {
      client_name: 'MyName',
      city_id: '3',
      email: 'myemail@gmail.com'
    }
  ];
```

This value I tried to display in html with this function:

```
  populateForm() {
      this.myform.patchValue({
      city_id: this.client.map(x => x.city_id),
      email: this.client.map(x => x.email),
      client_name: this.client.map(x => x.client_name)

    })
  }
```

email and client_name can display in html, but city_id no.

My html  code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <input formControlName="client_name"  placeholder="name">
    <input formControlName="email"  placeholder="email" >
    <input formControlName="city_id" Input placeholder="City" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="cityy">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptionsCity | async" [value]="item.name">
        <span>{{ item.name }}</span> 
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </form>
```

My result :

[image]

I want to show:

**`

> client_name: MyName  city_id: Florida    email: myemail@gmail.com

`**

I'm waiting for your suggestion.

Thank you
Edit:

```
  client: Client;
      populateForm() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
          params => {
            this.ws.getClientById(params['id']).subscribe(
              client => {
                this.client = client;
                this.patchForm();
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }

      patchForm() {
        this.myform.controls['client_name'].setValue(this.client.clientName);
        this.editClientForm.controls['city_id'].setValue(this.client.city);
        this.editClientForm.controls['email'].setValue(this.client.email);
    }
```

Class:

```
export class Client {
   clientName: string;
   email: string;
   city: City[];}

export class City {
  city_id: string;
  name: string;}
```

Cityes

```
    cityes: City[] = [];

    selectedCity: string;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.ws.getAllCity().subscribe(
      cityes => {
          this.cityes = cityes.map((city) => {
          return new City(city);
        });
          console.log(cityes) //return all my city
      }
    );

 this.selectedCity = this.cityes.filter(
      x => x.city_id === this.client.city
      .map(x => x.city_id)[0])
      .map(y => y.name).join('')
      console.log(this.cityes) //cityes is empty
     }
```

**Update**

```
  patchForm() {
    this.myform.controls['client_name'].setValue(this.client.clientName);
    this.editClientForm.controls['email'].setValue(this.client.email);
    this.editClientForm.controls['city_id'].setValue(this.selectedCity = this.cityes.filter(
     x => x.city_id === this.client.city
     .map(x => x.city_id)[0])
     .map(y => y.name).join(''))
 }
}
```

Comment: it's because you have `city_id: '3',` in client array which you are patching to formcontrol

Comment: Can you tried something how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to show the city name by default before typing anything in the autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, I want to show city name by default. In this exp. Florida

Comment: Can you please?

Comment: Check my answer.if this is something you are looking for. Also updated the stackblitz

Comment: ..I have posted my answer. it should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I have added `[(ngModel)] = "selectedCity"` to set the default value in the textbox before typing in the autocomplete . I have set the value of the property `selectedCity` in ts file. I have also changed `[formControl]="city_id"` to match it with the ts file formControl property. Now `Florida` will be displayed by default.

Below is the full code -

**autocomplete-overview-example.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <input formControlName="client_name"  placeholder="name">
    <input formControlName="email"  placeholder="email" >
    <input formControlName="city_id" placeholder="City" [(ngModel)] = "selectedCity" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" Input [formControl]="city_id">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptionsCity | async" [value]="item.name">
        <span>{{ item.name }}</span> 
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 
  </form>
```

**autocomplete-overview-example.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

export class City {
  constructor(public name: string, public city_id: string) { }
}
export class Client {
  constructor(public client_name: string, public city_id: string, public email: string) { }
}
/**
 * @title Autocomplete overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-overview-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredStates: Observable<any[]>;
 filteredOptionsCity: any;
  city_id: FormControl = new FormControl();
  myform: FormGroup;


  city: City[] = [
    {
      name: 'Arkansas',
      city_id: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'California',
      city_id: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Florida',
      city_id: '3'
    },
    {
      name: 'Texas',
      city_id: '4'
    }
  ];
  client: Client[] = [
    {
      client_name: 'MyName',
      city_id: '3',
      email: 'myemail@gmail.com'
    }
  ];
  selectedCity:string = this.city.filter(x=> x.city_id == this.client.map(x => x.city_id)[0]).map( y => y.name).join("");

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {


    this.myform = this.fb.group({
      'city_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'client_name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'email': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

ngOnInit(){
   this.populateForm();
   this.filteredOptionsCity = this.city_id.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterCity(value))
    );

}
filterCity(val: string): City[] {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      console.log(this.city)
      return this.city.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }

    return this.city;
  }
  populateForm() {

    this.myform.patchValue({
      city_id: this.client.map(x => x.city_id),
      email: this.client.map(x => x.email),
      client_name: this.client.map(x => x.client_name)

    });

    console.log(this.myform.controls);

  }

}
```

Here is working updated link for stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-gpfwjr

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In stackblitz works good, but in my realy project not function. Please if you can, look my edit post and suggest me, what is the problem in my project. Thank you so much

Comment: you are setting `city_id` to an array `this.client.city` in `this.editClientForm.controls['city_id'].setValue(this.client.city);` it should be a single value like `this.client.city.map(x => x.city_id).join("");`

Comment: selectedCity:string = this.cityes.filter(x=> x.city_id == this.client.city).map(x => x.city_id).join('');
-->Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'City[]'

Comment: have you used `ngModel` like in the example above? what is cityes? why are you filtering it

Comment: it should be `selectedCity:string = this.cityes.filter(x=> x.city_id == this.client.city.map(x => x.city_id)[0]).map(x => x.city.name).join('');`

Comment: @OnaBi try with my above code selectedCity, you also need to use `ngModel`

Comment: In html -->         <input formControlName="city_id" placeholder="City" [(ngModel)] = "selectedCity" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
        autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="city_id">

Comment: in ts -->     cityes: City[] = []; selectedCity: string = this.cityes.filter(x => x.city_id === this.client.city.map(x => x.city_id)[0]).map(x => x.name).join('');

Comment: Show only city_id

Comment: console.log(this.cityes.filter(x => x.city_id === this.client.city.map(x => x.city_id)[0]).map(x => x.name).join(''))
Is empty

Comment: @OnaBi can you post the conent of  `this.cityes` maybe there is not data yet in that array when you are using filter in it.

Comment: Yes, I can see now, this cityes is empty, why!!!! ws get me all city. Please I edit my post. What is the problem in my code?!

Comment: @OnaBi set the value of  `this.selectedCity` inside `populateForm() ` just before where you are calling `this.patchForm();` .. or you can do after that also .

Comment: I set code inside   patchForm() { }  like in my update post but is empty in input

Comment: @OnaBi when are you calling the `populateForm()` ? can you post that?

Comment: populateForm() is in  ngOnInit() {}  My input is empty, I think because the cities are empty

Comment: please can you suggest me, what is the problem with my code?